# Convert a database from MongoDB to a R data frame using Rmongo

Tags: r, mongodb

I am trying to obtain a database that comes from Mongo DB to R, so I can make anlaysis on it. The bridge between these two is a R package: Rmongo.
As I have some policy rules, I cannot show you the dataset and my output, so I will try to explain as best as possible.

My two first commands, after installing the package, are these ones:

`mg1 <- mongoDbConnect("test", "localhost", 27018)`

`dbShowCollections(mg1)`

Which works, as it shows the collection, or the different variables.
Then, I can use the commands made by the Rmongo package, meaning:

`query = dbGetQuery(mg1, 'address_history','{}')`

This normally returns a data frame with all the variables on each column. But, because it is a nested file, I only get the first three variables (out of around fifty) because they are at the top of the nest. For the rest, I get one column of the data frame with the json code (so of approximately 50 variables) that I cannot seem to turn in a data frame. If someone is familiar with that, please help me.

I already saw on Stack Overflow a way to do it manually thanks to gsub, and in general pattern with the code, but this code is dissimilar, and doing it manually will not make it work.

Furthermore, there is also another command via the Rmongo package:

`query2 = dbGetQueryForKeys(mg1, 'address_history', '{}', '{address:1}')`

where I can return the variable that I want. Unfortunately, because this is a nested file, it also cannot find the variables that are not in the top of the nest.

Is there another command or another package that I can use? I am open to any other opportunity to get this dataset (very large) into an R data frame, so I can make any inferences.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried just now setting up Rmongo and mongolite for R. I got mongolite working in minutes with the [starter data locally](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/import-data/) . I could not get even get the data I wanted inserted using Rmongo.

I think if you try installing mongolite you will find their documentation and package simpler. https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite

Comment: Hi Sam!! After using the mongolite command, I have a data frame. But I chose 14 variables, so I should have 15 columns. Unfortunately, the description of the object is a data frame of two variables: so it doesn't separate the 14 last columns: only the id is differentiated. I wanted to know if there is a way to fix that?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data in mongo's json format?